# How to set sheet name while exporting excel using display tag?

Tags: export-to-excel, displaytag

I am using display tag to export excel sheets. I can set the name of the excel file to whatever I want.

But I also want to set the name of the excel sheet inside the file. Right now by default it is set to ' - ' which does not make any sense.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

in property name tag pass like 
${RequiredString/bean property / value from session}

for ex. 
what I am doing is ${applicationName}

Here 'applicatinName' is my property declared in action class which will set every time request is submitted.